# "jQuery("#marquee").marquee is not a function" error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, marquee

I'm trying to use marquee plugin of jQuery.
but i get this error in FireBug console `jQuery("#marquee").marquee is not a function`.
My code is this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.marquee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){ 
        jQuery("#marquee").marquee(); 
    });
</script>
```

and my html is:

```
<ul id="marquee" class="marquee"> 
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using this marquee plugin:
http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm

What's the problem?

**-----EDIT-----**
I tested it on a stand alone page that had nothing except marquee codes and it worked!
I think other libraries that i'm using are making problem.
My entire `<head>` is:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="generator" content="Joomla! 1.7 - Open Source Content Management" />
<title>title</title>
<link href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=89&amp;Itemid=559&amp;format=feed&amp;type=rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" />
<link href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=89&amp;Itemid=559&amp;format=feed&amp;type=atom" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" />
<link href="http://localhost/joomla/index.php?option=com_search&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=89&amp;Itemid=559&amp;format=opensearch" rel="search" title="title" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joomla/media/system/css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joomla/plugins/content/attachments/attachments.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joomla/plugins/content/attachments/attachments1.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/system/css/jquery.marquee.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="/joomla/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/joomla/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/joomla/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/joomla/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/joomla/media/system/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/joomla/plugins/content/attachments/attachments_refresh.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="media/system/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="media/system/js/jquery.marquee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function keepAlive() {  var myAjax = new Request({method: "get", url: "index.php"}).send();} window.addEvent("domready", function(){ keepAlive.periodical(840000); });
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

        SqueezeBox.initialize({});
        SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
            parse: 'rel'
        });
    });
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

        SqueezeBox.initialize({});
        SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal-button'), {
            parse: 'rel'
        });
    });

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function (){ 
    jQuery("#marquee").marquee(); 
});
</script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/joomla/plugins/content/jumultithumb/assets/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joomla/templates/siteground-j16-25/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/joomla/templates/siteground-j16-25/js/CreateHTML5Elements.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/joomla/templates/siteground-j16-25/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/joomla/templates/siteground-j16-25/js/sgmenu.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does Firebug give you a 404 error in the network pane for `jquery.marquee.js`?

Comment: Why aren't you using the short jQuery syntax (`$`)?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: No! It gives the code!

Comment: @egasimus: Because I'm using other libraries too.

Comment: You might want to add which marquee plugin you're using.

Comment: @Yoshi: http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm . but i believe that plugin has no problem (its examples work well)

Comment: Are you also importing the stylesheet, `jquery.marquee.css`?

Comment: It looks as though the authors of the plugin used the short syntax in their source code (which is *not* standard practice).

Comment: @BrianDriscoll working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mjgasner/vdAfX/1/ took like 3 minutes just copying the code from the marquee site... must be something else he's doing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing your updated question the problem is clear. You're loading jquery a second time (3rd last line) which, of course, overwrites all plugins loaded previously. And as the call to `.marquee` is asynchrones (callback to the ready event) the plugin is gone at the time the callback is called.

Solution: Remove that second time you're loading jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){ 
        jQuery("#marquee").marquee(); 
    });
</script>
```

in the body

Heres an example of what i'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/mjgasner/m64xQ/

Right now it doesn't work, but if you change the javascript load to nowrap (body) it works.

Comment: He already has this in the head, why would moving it to the body help?

Comment: @MikeyG: Thanks but as i said above i did this (put js in body after defining `li` tags) and it didn't helped. and in your case result is because you are loading JQuery and plugin in body itself and not in the code so calling it before defining makes the problem.